# Build Boost.Locale with iconv for iOS

Tags: c++, ios, boost, boost-locale, b2

I'm currently trying to build Boost.Locale for iOS, but I can't get it to find the iconv lib (I'm successfully building other parts of Boost for iOS, such as `thread` or `filesystem`).

I've tried to let Boost.Build find it by itself, I've tried to set the `ICONV_PATH` variable to point at the iPhoneOS SDK iconv lib. Checking the Jamfile in Boost.Locale, I stumbled upon that rule:

```
lib iconv 
  : 
  : <search>$(ICONV_PATH)/lib <link>shared <runtime-link>shared
  :
  : <include>$(ICONV_PATH)/include 
  ;
```

So I thought setting [`-sICONV_PATH`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/locale/doc/html/building_boost_locale.html#bb_build_opts) to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk/usr` would be enough, as this directory contains a `lib` and an `include` folder which contain the iconv lib and header, but Boost still fails to find it, and spits:

```
iconv (libc)             : no
iconv (separate)         : no
icu                      : no
icu (lib64)              : no
Boost.Locale needs either iconv or ICU library to be built.
```

Note that I always invoke `b2` with the `--reconfigure` option, and thus it's not the result of the caching of a previous invocation (which would have a trailing `(cached)` in the list above.

So, is there a way to correctly point Boost at the iconv implementation present in the iOS SDK? I'd like to avoid building a separate iconv if possible.

Answer (score 5):

I was running into similar problems. After some digging and some red herrings I learned that boost detects iconv by compiling the has_iconv.cpp program. In my case (using the boost.sh script that a lot of people seem to use for compiling for iOS) there were a lot of compilation errors in config.log caused by an incorrect using-syntax in user-config.jam . So the problem - at least for me - wasn't getting ICONV_PATH set but making the detection program compile at all! Perhaps you have a similar problem.

I did a [full write up of finding in my blog](http://metashapes.com/blog/building-boost-locale-ios) if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

You should receive the following log output when building

> If iconv library is not found on Darwin/Mac OS X builds  make sure
>   there is no multiple iconv installations  and provide -sICONV_PATH
>   build option to point to correct location of iconv library.

First you need to Bootstrap the location, where $ICU = ICU root directory *and* the directory in which the build ICU build products are ("bin/", "include/", etc.):

```
.\bootstrap --with-icu=$ICU
```

Then

```
.\b2 boost.locale.icu=on boost.locale.std=off -sICU_PATH="$ICU" --with-chrono --with-locale --with-system --with-thread link=static stage cxxflags="-miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -stdlib=libc++"
```

Comment: Do you mean iconv instead of ICU? I'm trying to build that with iconv specifically (and yes, I received that warning, and as my post mention, I specified `sICONV_PATH`).

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but here is a working config that supports Boost.Locale on iOS using the iconv library (boost v1_64_0). An implementation is available from https://github.com/Cogosense/iOSBoostFramework that uses a Makefile to build a boost framework for armv7, armv7s, arm64, i386, and x86_64 architectures.

To build 32bit ARM create a **user-config.jam** with the following content:

```
using clang-darwin : arm                                                                                                                                                  
    : xcrun --sdk iphoneos clang++
    : <cxxflags>"-miphoneos-version-min=8.0  -arch armv7s -DBOOST_AC_USE_PTHREADS -DBOOST_SP_USE_PTHREADS -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -D_LITTLE_ENDIAN -Wall -pedantic -Wno-unused-variable"
      <linkflags>"-arch armv7s"
      <striper>
    ;
```

the architecture can also be set to **armv7**, change the value of cxxflags to your liking, but the **-arch** flag is required.

build boost for the 32bit iPhone target with the following build command:

```
BOOST_BUILD_USER_CONFIG=<path-to-arm32-jam-config>/user-config.jam \
SDK_PATH=$(xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-platform-path) \
./b2 -sICONV_PATH=$SDK_PATH/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr \
    toolset=clang-darwin-arm \
    target-os=iphone
```

To build 64bit ARM create a **user-config.jam** with the following content:

```
using clang-darwin : arm64                                                                                                                                                  
    : xcrun --sdk iphoneos clang++
    : <cxxflags>"-miphoneos-version-min=8.0  -arch arm64 -DBOOST_AC_USE_PTHREADS -DBOOST_SP_USE_PTHREADS -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -D_LITTLE_ENDIAN -Wall -pedantic -Wno-unused-variable"
      <linkflags>"-arch arm64"
      <striper>
    ;
```

build boost for the 64bit iPhone target with the following build command:

```
BOOST_BUILD_USER_CONFIG=<path-to-arm64-jam-config>/user-config.jam \
SDK_PATH=$(xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-platform-path) \
./b2 -sICONV_PATH=$SDK_PATH/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr \
    toolset=clang-darwin-arm64 \
    target-os=iphone
```

To build 32bit x86 simulator create a **user-config.jam** with the following content:

```
using clang-darwin : x86                                                                                                                                                  
    : xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator clang++
    : <cxxflags>"-miphoneos-version-min=8.0  -arch i386 -DBOOST_AC_USE_PTHREADS -DBOOST_SP_USE_PTHREADS -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11  -Wall -pedantic -Wno-unused-variable"
      <linkflags>"-arch i386"
      <striper>
    ;
```

build boost for the 32bit iPhone Simulator with the following build command:

```
BOOST_BUILD_USER_CONFIG=<path-to-x86-jam-config>/user-config.jam \
SDK_PATH=$(xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-platform-path)
./b2 -sICONV_PATH=$SDK_PATH/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr \
    toolset=clang-darwin-i386 \
    target-os=iphone
```

To build 64bit x86 simulator create a **user-config.jam** with the following content:

```
using clang-darwin : x86_64                                                                                                                                                 
    : xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator clang++
    : <cxxflags>"-miphoneos-version-min=8.0  -arch x86_64 -DBOOST_AC_USE_PTHREADS -DBOOST_SP_USE_PTHREADS -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11  -Wall -pedantic -Wno-unused-variable"
      <linkflags>"-arch x86_64"
      <striper>
    ;
```

build boost for the 64bit iPhone Simulator with the following build command:

```
BOOST_BUILD_USER_CONFIG=<path-to-x86_64-jam-config>/user-config.jam \
SDK_PATH=$(xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-platform-path)
./b2 -sICONV_PATH=$SDK_PATH/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr \
    toolset=clang-darwin-x86_64 \
    target-os=iphone
```

Comment: I've tried to do it on Boost 1.74.0 - got failed. Nothing working for me. Now trying to use it for 1.64.0. Will reply later.

Comment: @AlexandrKirilov In the GitHub Repo linked in this answer is a 1_73_0_dev branch that has patches for boost 1.73 - it is working. I expect the same path will work for 1.74.